# Can I import KML and CSV data into same Fusion Table without using Merge Tables?

Tags: csv, kml, google-fusion-tables

I am working on a project and we are looking to automate a mapping application that we have. We have a Python script that converts our data into a CSV file then creates the associated KML  file for that data. Is there any way to import both of these files into the same Fusion Table without going through the hassle of creating two tables and then merging them together on a unique key or possibly merge the CSV into the KML file?

Answer (score 0):

If you know how to create the KML, put the KML fragment required for FusionTables in the correct column in the CSV.